# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Row'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

new student here. Having issues with this error popping up while attempting to have a playlist app add a song to a selected playlist. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, my limited knowledge hasn't yield great search results. I'm unsure if this is a db model setup error or an issue with the form submit as I'm not familiar with this traceback issue yet.

Traceback log:

```
File "/home/naitheas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 172, in __call__
    return self.meta.render_field(self, kwargs)
  
File "/home/naitheas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/meta.py", line 64, in render_field
    return field.widget(field, **render_kw)
  
File "/home/naitheas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/widgets/core.py", line 351, in __call__
    for val, label, selected in field.iter_choices():
  
File "/home/naitheas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/fields/choices.py", line 116, in _choices_generator
    yield (value, label, self.coerce(value) == self.data)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Row'
```

db models:

```
class Playlist(db.Model):

    #Playlist.

    __tablename__ = "playlists"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)

    description = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

   
    songs = db.relationship('Song', secondary='playlists_songs', backref='playlists')



    def __repr_(self):
        return f"<Playlist {self.name}-{self.description}.>"    
  

class Song(db.Model):

    #Song.

    __tablename__ = "songs"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)

    title = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    artist = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    

   

class PlaylistSong(db.Model):

    #Mapping of a song to a playlist

    __tablename__ = "playlists_songs"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    playlist_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey(
        'playlists.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'),primary_key=True)

    song_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('songs.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'),primary_key=True)
```

View Route:

```
@app.route("/playlists/<int:playlist_id>/add-song", methods=["GET", "POST"])

def add_song_to_playlist(playlist_id):

    #Add a playlist and redirect to list.

    playlist = Playlist.query.get_or_404(playlist_id)
    form = NewSongForPlaylistForm()

    # Restrict form to songs not already on this playlist

    curr_on_playlist = [s.id for s in playlist.songs]
    form.song.choices = (db.session.query(Song.id,Song.title)
                        .filter(Song.id.notin_(curr_on_playlist))
                        .all())
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        song = Song.query.get(form.song.data)
        playlists.songs.append(song)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(f"/playlists/{playlist_id}")
    else:
        return render_template('add_song_to_playlist.html',
                             playlist=playlist,
                             form=form)
```

WTForm, if needed for ref:

```
    class NewSongForPlaylistForm(FlaskForm):
        song = SelectField('Song To Add',coerce=int)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure your code is [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly for posting, and also format your exception stack trace as if it were code. If you want to use backticks for code blocks, you must use *three* on *each side*, which are in each case *on a line by themselves* (except that on the opening line you can write `python` after the backticks to specify the language). Otherwise, make sure that you put an *extra* four spaces in front of *each* line of code, and that there is a blank line *before and after* the code.

Comment: Thanks! Totally missed the format blurb on the question form =/ Hopefully cleaned up to match forum expectations.